# Creating a column just in the entity model and not in the database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, properties

I have a table that has a number of columns and I have written a stored procedure to get the data from it for a grid that is displayed to the user. For certain purposes, I also return the total number of rows in the table. I return it with the table type itself in the edmx and therefore, I need to create a column 'total' just in the Entity Model. How do I do this? I don't know what kind of a property is this. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create computed columns in your database tables. In the EF model you just annotate the corresponding properties with the DatabaseGenerated attribute:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public double Totalll { get; set; }
```

Or with fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Income>().Property(t => t.Totalll)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
```

Comment: I don't use the code first approach. Instead I use the designer. I don't know what is the exact term. All I do to add SPs and to update the model is right click on it and click Update Model from Database.

Comment: Also, what I want is a scalar property?